# output error in c++

Tags: c++

I am having a very strange problem in a simple program and have been unable to reach any logical conclusion. When I redirect output from my program to a file, then I get a different result that I get when printing to stdout. When I print to a file, the result is correct. I don't understand why it would be different in the first place. Here is a snippet. Any ideas?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    double x = i*h;
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
        double y = j*h;
        double bi = h*h*f(x,y);
        if (x+h == 1.0) {
            bi += boundary_f(1,y);
        }
    if (y+h == 1.0) {
        bi += boundary_f(x,1);
    }
    cout << "i=" << i << "; j=" << j << "; b=" << bi << "\n";
    b(k,1) = bi;
    ++k;
}
```

I get different results when printing to stdout and redirect to file! It seems like the conditions y+h==1.0 does not evaluate to true even when y+h is 1.0 when the output to stdout but when redirected to file, it evaluates correctly.

Comment: Does the program write to cerr as well? If so, is the problem you're seeing to do with the cout and cerr outputs getting intermingled?

Comment: no only cout. It seems like the conditions (y+h == 1.0) evaluate differently when redirecting to cout vs file.

Comment: @user236215: Can you show how you are running the program from the command line and some, if not all of the output? Without this or the full code it's not really possible to either recreate the problem or speculate on why it's happening.

Comment: sure will attach it in a min.

Comment: never mind guys. @Naveen is right. There was a bug in my floating point comparison in the way I was computing the relative error. I fixed it and it works more predictably now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing `double` values for absolute equality is bad. You can not gurantee whether the program enters 'if' condition or not. Instead what you can do is something like : `fabs(y+h-1.0) < EPSILON` where EPSILON will be something `10^-5.`

Comment: I understand. This is a simple example. I usually compare by comparing the absolute error to an epsilon. But when I substitute that logic, in this case, I still get different outputs. This really is driving me nuts. I am looking into potential buffer overflow issues..

Comment: you were right. There was a bug in my floating point comparison function. I fixed it and it works ok now. thanks!